# Prove $\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \sin x}{x}$ does not exsists

Tags: calculus, limits

> Prove $\lim _{x\to 0}\:\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \sin x}{x}$ does not exsists

---

what I did is:

$$-1=\lim _{x\to 0^-}\:\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \sin x}{x}\ne\lim _{x\to 0^+}\:\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \sin x}{x}=0$$

so $\lim _{x\to 0}\:\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \sin x}{x}$ does not exist.

Is this correct and if I want to prove it  by Heine ,How can I prove it?

thanks

Comment: Is [.] the floor function?

Comment: @toliveira it's the integer that smaller than x

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Comment: yes but I want to prove it by Heine any idea how to prove it ?

Comment: Wouldn't $a_n = 1/n$ and $b_n = -1/n$ do the job? (edit: here I would be using a corollary of Heine's definition, not the definition itself)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos answer is more complete. Please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct.

Proving using sequences is easy: if $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}n$ ($n\in\mathbb N$), then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and the limit$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor a_n\rfloor\sin a_n}{a_n}$$does not exist, since if you take the subsequence of those $a_n$ with odd $n$ you get $-1$ and if you take the subsequence of those $a_n$ with even $n$ you get $0$,

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Since the limit for $\frac {sinx}{x}$ is known to be 1 for x tending to $0$, you just have to analyze the floor function at x =0. But the floor function is not continuous at any integer value of x (as you can quickly check) since  $\lim_{x \to a^+} [x] = a $ and $\lim_{x \to a^-} [x] = a-1$ whenever a is an integer